# JavaScript Speech Recognition

Tags: javascript, api, case, speech

Is there a JavaScript Speech Recognition API that works in the following way.

I have a set of sentences of this format: "[piece] to [location]".
There are a set of possible values for piece and location. The want the speech recognition to find the closest match to the possible sentences that I have. Is there an API that works like this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.talater.com/annyang/ the complexity is your job to make

Comment: https://api.ai/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a JavaScript Speech Recognition API - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/SpeechRecognition). Your question asking about recognising specific words and matching them to a predefined set of sentences may be leaning more towards machine learning / natural language services though.

It's possible you'll want the [grammars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/grammars) property to build out your list but equally, it may be that you'll want to integrate with another service to make more accurate decisions around the words people use.